# Computer Graphics card crash

Tags: graphics, crash

I just bought a Sapphire ATI Radeon 6870 Graphics card.

My Computer is a:

Mainoard: ASRock X58 Extreme 3 Mainboard

Power Supply: CoolerMaster GX 750W

CPU: Intel i7 3,4 GHz

My computer keeps getting messed up. I don't know why... I'm gaming or watching a video and suddenly my Screen Turns into Stripes and nothing works... I need to Restart the PC.

Comment: Sounds like an overheating problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem with my 6770 until Catalyst 1.8 was released a few days ago. Try updating your video drivers.

[Windows 7 x64 Driver download link](http://sites.amd.com/us/game/downloads/pages/radeon_win7-64.aspx)

Comment: Yeah I tried that several times. Nothing worked :(

Answer (score 1):

Overheating is likely the cause, but inadequate power supply is on the list too. Try to estimate total power usage of your computer and see if it's any where near nominal value of power supply, which is could be easily by 20% higher then real value.

Comment: I already bought a new Power Supply wich has 750W. My graphic Card needs 500W. But i think overheating is the cause. I dont know why,  I set my Vent up to 100% performance, But when I play WoW, or HoN, after about 30 Minutes my Graphic Crashes. My Graphic Card is 60° / 140F at this point. I just checked the Airflow of my Case. It's very good everything is cool. I dont know why my Graphic card is always Overheating. Maybe its a defect or something.